# How to check if remote database MYSQL is available

Tags: c#, mysql

I need register the user access on my webpage aspx in MySQL remote Database.
But this MySQL remote Database it could be unavailable.

I have tried this code, but how to execute the **RegisterUSer()** method in the **bool IsServerConnected()** method ?

```
public bool IsServerConnected()
{
    using (var l_oConnection =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            l_oConnection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (OdbcException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


private void RegisterUSer()
{
    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = @String.Format(" INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_user ");
        sql += String.Format(" ... ");

        using (OdbcCommand command =
                new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

**#Edit 01**

[image]

Error :

> The type or namespace name 'resultType' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you can just ping the server address and check the result

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a "wrapper" method that calls first to IsServerConnected() and depending on the returned boolean then calls RegisterUSer() or throws an error if the database is not availiable.

Quick and dirty pseudocode

```
private resultType ChickenWrapMethod() 
{ 
    if (!IsServerConnected()) 
    { 
        //Throw some error here and exit
    }

    RegisterUSer()
}
```

BTW...in my opinion you should consider opening the sql connection out of the methods so it can be shared by both operations

Comment: Thanks, but please see **#Edit 01** in my first question

Comment: Hi! My response is just pseudocode, you need to define some return type, maybe a boolean, or just return void.

P.S. And give it a more professional name than ChickenWrapMethod ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in c#. I hope I was helpful.

```
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    var ping = new Ping();

    var reply = ping.Send("XX.XX.XX.XXX", 60 * 1000); // 1 minute time out (in ms)

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        Response.Write("Server XX.XX.XX.XXX is up");
        RegisterUSer();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Server XX.XX.XX.XXX is down");
    }
```